# User Authenticatin in Shiny

Tags: r, authentication, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm using the `Shinyauthr` package to authenticate different users to access different components in dashboard.
I have three users, user1, user2 and user 3.
When user 1 logs in the dashboard, they should see a Datatable,
When user 2 logs in the dashboard, they should see a histogram,
When user 3 logs in the dashboard, they should see both the histogram and the Datatable in one page.

I've been able to manage authenticate for user1 and user2 but I'm stuck at the logic code for user3.

app.R code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
library(shinyauthr)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
library(lubridate)

source("global.R")

# How many days should sessions last?
cookie_expiry <- 7

# This function must return a data.frame with columns user and sessionid.  Other columns are also okay
# and will be made available to the app after log in.

get_sessions_from_db <- function(conn = db, expiry = cookie_expiry) {
  dbReadTable(conn, "sessions") %>%
    mutate(login_time = ymd_hms(login_time)) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    filter(login_time > now() - days(expiry))
}

# This function must accept two parameters: user and sessionid. It will be called whenever the user
# successfully logs in with a password.
add_session_to_db <- function(user, sessionid, conn = db) {
  tibble(user = user, sessionid = sessionid, login_time = as.character(now())) %>%
    dbWriteTable(conn, "sessions", ., append = TRUE)
}

db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbCreateTable(db, "sessions", c(user = "TEXT", sessionid = "TEXT", login_time = "TEXT"))

user_base <- tibble(
  user = c("user1", "user2"),
  password = c("pass1", "pass2"),
  password_hash = sapply(c("pass1", "pass2"), sodium::password_store),
  permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two")
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    
    title = "shinyauthr",
    tags$li(
      class = "dropdown",
      style = "padding: 8px;",
      shinyauthr::logoutUI("logout")
    ),
    tags$li(
      class = "dropdown",
      tags$a(
        icon("github"),
        href = "https://github.com/paulc91/shinyauthr",
        title = "See the code on github"
      )
    )
    
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = TRUE,
    div(textOutput("welcome"), style = "padding: 20px")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    shinyauthr::loginUI(
      "login", 
      cookie_expiry = cookie_expiry, 
      additional_ui = tagList(
        tags$p("test the different outputs from the sample logins below
             as well as an invalid login attempt.", class = "text-center"),
        HTML(knitr::kable(user_base[, -3], format = "html", table.attr = "style='width:100%;'"))
      )
    ),
    uiOutput("testUI")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # call login module supplying data frame, user and password cols and reactive trigger
  credentials <- shinyauthr::loginServer(
    id = "login",
    data = user_base,
    user_col = user,
    pwd_col = password_hash,
    sodium_hashed = TRUE,
    cookie_logins = TRUE,
    sessionid_col = sessionid,
    cookie_getter = get_sessions_from_db,
    cookie_setter = add_session_to_db,
    log_out = reactive(logout_init())
  )
  
  # call the logout module with reactive trigger to hide/show
  logout_init <- shinyauthr::logoutServer(
    id = "logout",
    active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth)
  )
  
  observe({
    if (credentials()$user_auth) {
      shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    } else {
      shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
    }
  })
  
  user_info <- reactive({
    credentials()$info
  })
  
  user_data <- reactive({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    
    if (user_info()$permissions == "admin") {
      DF2DT
    } else if (user_info()$permissions == "standard") {
      Hist
    }
  })
  
  output$welcome <- renderText({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    
    glue("Welcome {user_info()$name}")
  })
  
  output$testUI <- renderUI({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        tags$h2(glue("Your permission level is: {user_info()$permissions}.
                     You logged in at: {user_info()$login_time}."
                     )),
        box(
          width = NULL,
          status = "primary",
          title = ifelse(user_info()$permissions == "admin", "DF Data", "Storms Data"),
          DT::renderDT(user_data(), options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
          
        ), 
        
        box(width = NULL, 
            renderPlot(user_data()))
      )
    )
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

global.R code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)


# User DB ####
user_base <- tibble(
  user = c("user1", "user2", "user3"), 
  password = c("pass1", "pass2", "pass3"), 
  name =c("user 1" , "user 2", "user 3")
)


# Histogram ####
set.seed(41)
Distribution <- rnorm(20, mean = 50, sd = 20)
DistributionDF <- data.frame(var=Distribution)
Hist <- ggplot(DistributionDF, aes(var)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=10, color="white", fill="#5DA7DB") +
  theme_minimal()
Hist


# Table ####
Indicator <- c("Hypothermia", "CPAP use")
`2021 Q1` <- c(1, 0)
`2021 Q2` <- c(0.6, 0.1)
`2021 Q3` <- c(0.1, 0.6)
`2021 Q4` <- c(0, 1)
DF <- data.frame(Indicator, `2021 Q1`, `2021 Q2`, `2021 Q3`, `2021 Q4`, check.names= F)

# Variables for DT styling
percentageValues <- c(0,0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1)
fontColors <- c("#000","#000","#000","#000","#000","#000","#fff","#000","#fffffff","#000","#fff")
colorRamp <- c("#ff0000","#ffc000","#FFAE6D","#2146C7","#F0FF42","#FB2576","#c45911","#4C6793","#562B08","#533483","#385623") 

# Create a Datatable from the DF
DF2DT <- datatable(DF) %>%
  formatPercentage(
    columns = c(2:5), 0
  ) %>%
  formatStyle(
    columns = c(2:5), 
    color = styleEqual(percentageValues, fontColors), 
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(percentageValues, colorRamp)
  )
```

Comment: Wrap the two `box`es (I assume they are the table and histogram you mention) in another uiOutput and render them appropriately.  or simply return `NULL` from the existing `renderDT` and `renderPlot`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. However, When you click user 1 it loads the Datatable and not the plot. The same way with user2. It loads the plot instead of the table. Any clue of how to switch this so that the code has a flow of logic?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an MWE based on my comment:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(
            title="Testing..."
        ), 
        dashboardSidebar(
            radioButtons("user", "User", c("User 1", "User 2", "User 3"))
        ),
        dashboardBody(
            box(width=4, plotOutput("plot")),
            box(width=8, tableOutput("table"))
        )
      )

##### SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        if (input$user == "User 1") return (NULL)
        mtcars %>% 
            ggplot() +
            geom_point(aes(x=wt, y=mpg))
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
        if (input$user == "User 2") return (NULL)
        mtcars
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It should be easy to adapt to use your `credentials()` rather than my `radioButtons`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. However, When you click user 1 it loads the Datatable and not the plot. The same way with user2. It loads the plot instead of the table. Any clue of how to switch this so that the code has a flow of logic?

Comment: Yes.  Simply edit the `if` statements.  You should be able to figure that out for yourself. You did say "When user 1 logs in the dashboard, they should see a Datatable"...

Comment: My mistake in the question. Yes, I have a hack but it's not the appropriate one. I interchanged the username. On the output is OK but codewise, not OK

Comment: Kindly assist please